# XCode7 beta2 and iOS8.4 on device not working

Tags: ios, xcode7-beta2

After the update to iOS8.4 on my device XCode7.2b stopped working. My device is not selectable in the list of devices and XCode says "Could not find Developer Disk Image".

Any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution:

Just copy XCode 8.4 folder from this location:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSup‌​port
```

to this location:

```
/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Devi‌​ceSupport
```

Answer (score 1):

The "official" solution it likely to be wait until next week when 9.0b3 comes out. (8.4 came out *after* the last iOS 9 beta.)

Comment: You have to expect problems when running beta software. Xcode 6 supports 8.4.

Comment: (And you found a workaround. I thought it was worth mentioning that the problem will likely just go away next week.)

Comment: I appreciate you posting an "official" solution, but @netshark1000 deserves the accepted solution